# Prevent ZSH from saving $PREBUFFER into history after interrupt

Tags: zsh

In a continuation context (`$PREBUFFER` is not empty) like below:

```
$ echo 1 \
$
```

Right after I type Ctrl+C to interrupt the input, ZSH will save `$PREBUFFER` into the history file:

```
...
: 1676711302:0;echo 1 \
```

How to prevent this behavior?

Comment: `$PREBUFFER` is what's left of the cursor in a zle widget. If you have pressed enter, `$PREBUFFER` like `$BUFFER` is empty as zle is editing a new line.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I don't think so. See this zle widget https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Zle/up-line-or-beginning-search#L11-L14